# Лимит сообщений в секунду, бот IRC на Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот

Помогите пожалуйста. Не могу сформировать логику работы.

Есть наистандартнейший бот для IRC на Python 3 на сокетах, написанный по инструкциям из интернета, с той поправкой, что были написаны некоторые дополнительные функции. Есть функция получения ника отправляющего.

Какие существуют способы подсчитать количество сообщений пользователя в секунду? Пользователей в чате далеко не один, поэтому у меня возникли проблемы.

Если это важно - бот ещё пишет сообщения в файл с помощью модуля logging в формате timestamp nick@ip сообщение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это уже небольшая, но всё же архитектурная задача, а значит, потенциальных решений может быть много, и конкретный выбор зависит от целей и перспектив проекта. Для начала определитесь, каким способом Вы хотите измерять количество чего-либо за какой-то промежуток времени:

#### Вариант 1. Число сообщений за "календарную" секунду

Здесь достаточно просто в какой-нибудь глобальной переменной словаре хранить количество сообщений от каждого пользователя и регулярно (в данном случае ежесекундно) обнулять все значения.

#### Вариант 2. Число сообщений за последнюю секунду (метод скользящего окна)

Здесь на можно поступить аналогично: сделать глобальную переменную словарь, но в значениях хранить список даты-времени сообщения от пользователя. И ежесекундно удалять оттуда записи, которые старше 1 секунды.

Конечно, вариантов куда больше: можно ещё регулярно пробегаться по Вашему файлу, или сохранять и смотреть активности юзверей с помощью БД. Можно даже комбинировать эти способы! Например, хранить активности в глобальных переменных для скорости работы, но при запуске считывать из БД или файла для поддержания постоянства между запусками программы (хотя вряд ли актуально для одной секунды). Таковы инженерные задачи, выбирайте, придумывайте любое решение оптимально подходящее для конкретного проекта.